# Frequency identification as a convex problem

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, algorithms, system-identification, optimization

Suppose I have two time series, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$: $x$ is the output of a sine wave generator, and $y$ is the generator's frequency setting. Given a training set of $(x, y)$ pairs, Is it possible to formulate a convex/quasi-convex optimization problem to build a predictor of some new $y$ given $x$?

The system is certainly non-linear, since you can double the signal amplitude without changing the output (the frequency). It seems like you need to perform an `argmax` in the frequency domain, which I believe is a quasi-convex operation. This limits what functions you can compose, so something like computing residuals may no longer be convex. My hunch though is there may be a clever recasting of the problem, or a duality argument, etc.

I'm sure neural nets are capable of it, but for sake of discussion assume I don't have the data/processing power.

Comment: [See Part III section 1.1](https://espace.library.uq.edu.au/data/UQ_10626/comparison-t.pdf?Expires=1531088767&Signature=bzWnf8oSbmkBMH~TWtJxfBN6ilD7rMMJIIKYBPKecjLIpqpdb207L-F8qcns3ljdxq6cWFgdduCZNzZntLP0Ns2B2tRZzH2AAWdOyKmplODQfA27tKWu1TyUuBdERDsTflnZaN7~SH4CIfLN0OVq9ZEqd4EayXrGDSmJpIHHFloCuvPr9GjWeKHjXC0O5k0CQvkkutIwexA7Hjt2R1zXozqGgwiZYTIPZ30-o0zOtsdTGGwNJN1zo8u~b0afw8QpkovV1EEZ17l5PzsQTLXiVWaNPsYNi3BQaVI1jU0KNp3LBUn~vVNC5tOuI5YKkI77JQAO2l0~9fF2sWPhRisUZw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJKNBJ4MJBJNC6NLQ)

Comment: @PeterK. ha, that will make a fine addition to my references library

Comment: @PeterK. this looks great - thanks for posting! I don't have enough rep to upvote your comment but consider this a +1

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a little old. Like 21+ years... 

Comment: @RedPanda no worries. I would do a longer actual answer, but I'm traveling and don't have easy access to a laptop... and hate composing actual answers on mobile.

Comment: Well, @peterk, I haven't properly thought about convergence behaviour of subspace-based parametric estimators, so it's always nice to see such things put into perspective

Comment: @PeterK., The link doesn't work. Do you have updated link? It's better strategy to link with some naming of what the link (For Google Search in case the link dies).

Comment: @Royi updated. Search for “Kootsookos Review Frequency Estimation Tracking” as the updated link will expire too.

Comment: @PeterK. Great! Are you aware of something similar which is more modern? Oh, Now I see it is you :-).

Comment: @RedPanda, I assume the frequency is not constant. Why is convexity so important to you in this context?